# Getting the exception like "Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 12 to TIMESTAMP"

Tags: java, mysql

Previously the column Data type is Date now I am changed to Timestamp 
Now if I tried to run the program am getting them  exception

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 12 to TIMESTAMP.
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1298)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getTimestampFast(ByteArrayRow.java:124)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6610)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:5928)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:5966)
 at org.hibernate.type.TimestampType.get(TimestampType.java:30)
 at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
 at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2096)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
 ... 40 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0000-00-00 00:00:00` is outside the range of a `TIMESTAMP` value (in fact, it won't work with a `DATE` field either). From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: I just hit this problem so +1 for the help, it's interesting that if you have a null timestamp, for example after just adding a new timestamp column, 'select ... where timestampcol is null' doesn't work - it won't return any rows.

Answer (score 10):

You can just add **zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull** to your connection `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`.

For me, it works perfectly.
pls refer to this [link](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/cannot-convert-value-0000-00-00-000000-from-column-xx-to-timestamp/#comment-1283) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` function to explicitly convert the value to TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess here that you're using MySQL :-) It uses "zero dates" as special placeholder - unfortunatelly, JDBC can not handle them by default.

The solution is to specify "zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" as parameter to your MySQL connection (either in datasource URL or as an additional property), e.g.:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

This will cause all such values to be retrieved as NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in you java code the field type is java.sql.Timestamp